# Apache Solr - Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id

Tags: indexing, solr, schema, unique-key

I'm using Solr7.1 (SolrCloud mode) and I don't have requirement to enforce document uniqueness.
Hence I marked `id` field (designated as unique key) in schema as `required="false"`.

`<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" multiValued="false" />`

`<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>`

And I am trying to index some documents using solr Admin UI and I am trying without specifying `'id'` field.

`{
 "cat": "books",
 "name": "JayStore"
}`


I was expecting it to index successfully but solr is throwing error saying 'mandatory unique key field id is missing'

Could some one guide me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please post the complete error log as that might provide exact info on what is happening

Comment: @suvartheec This is the response from "update" REST API
`
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":400,
    "QTime":2},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id",
    "code":400}}
`

and this is the message shown on admin UI:

`Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id`

Answer (score 3):

The `uniqueKey` field is required internally by Solr for certain features, such as using `cursorMark` - meaning that the field that is defined as a uniqueKey *is* required. It's also used for routing etc. inside SolrCloud by default (IIRC), so if it's not present Solr won't be able to shard your documents correctly. Setting it as not required in the schema won't relax that requirement.

But you can work around this by defining an UUID field, and [using a UUID Update Processor as described in the old wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UniqueKey#UUID_techniques). This will generate a unique UUID for each document when you index it, meaning each document will get a unique identificator attached by default.

> UUID is short for Universal Unique IDentifier. The UUID standard RFC-4122 includes several types of UUID with different input formats. There is a UUID field type (called UUIDField) in Solr 1.4 which implements version 4. Fields are defined in the schema.xml file with:
>
> `<fieldType name="uuid" class="solr.UUIDField" indexed="true" />`
>
> in Solr 4, this field must be populated via solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory.
>
> `<field name="id" type="uuid" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>`
>   `<updateRequestProcessorChain name="uuid">
>       <processor class="solr.UUIDUpdateProcessorFactory">
>         <str name="fieldName">id</str>
>       </processor>
>       <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" /
>   </updateRequestProcessorChain>`

Comment: makes sense. But documentation on `<uniqueKey>` xml element is somewhat confusing. It is like below:

`<!-- Field to use to determine and enforce document uniqueness.
      Unless this field is marked with required="false", it will be a required field
    -->
    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>`